# convert string literal to a date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a varchar2 field in my db with the format of for example -

```
2015-08-19 00:00:01.0
2014-01-11 00:00:01.0
etc.
```

I am trying to convert this to a date of format DD-MON-YYYY. For instance, 2015-08-19 00:00:01.0 should become 19-AUG-2015. I've tried

```
 select to_date(upgrade_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from connection_report_update
```

but even at this point I'am getting ORA-01830 date format ends before converting the entire input string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have details upto milli seconds, for which, you have to use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` with format model '`FF`'

```
select to_timestamp('2015-08-19 00:00:01.0' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-AUG-15 12.00.01.000000000 AM
```

And Date doesn't have a format itself, only the date output can be in a format. So, when you want it to be printed in a different format, you would need to again use a `TO_CHAR()` of the converted timestamp;

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('2015-08-19 00:00:01.0' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MON-YYYY') as result from dual;

RESULT
-----------
19-AUG-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store datetimes in a string???

Anyhow. To get from '2015-08-19 00:00:01.0' to a datetime with milliseconds (which is a `TIMESTAMP` in Oracle) use `to_timestamp`:

```
to_timestamp('2015-08-19 00:00:01.0', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
```

Then to get the desired output format, use `to_char`:

```
to_char(thedate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Together:

```
to_char(to_timestamp('2015-08-19 00:00:01.0', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: Oops, that was a tad late :-) I see that Maheswaran Ravisankar has already explained all this in his answer.

Comment: thanks. I have inherited the db from someone else.otherwise I would not have stored a string for a date field.

Answer (score -1):

You should be specifying the format that you want in the call of to_date not the current format:

```
select to_date(upgrade_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') from connection_report_update
```